# Installation failed, invalid APK. in Flash Builder Burrito

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder

I've created an app in Flash Builder "Burrito" for Android Phone. When I run the application there are no project warnings or errors. The .apk was compiled successfully. The emulator is running Andorid 2.2. However, when I push the .apk to the emulator I get "Invalid Apk" error.? Now I don't know how to resolve this problem. Please help me to solve this problem..

Thank you.

Comment: please dont write title in all caps

Answer (score 1):

Flex 4.5 is under beta, it was released just for demonstration. It is preview release, so wait for stable release.